# MVC 3 Entity Framework v5 CodeFirst Model compatibility errors

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I just started a new application that uses EF v5

I created a database in SQL Server without any tables. I am trying to Get EF to create the table from the model code but an error occurs when it tries to execute:

```
 c.Database.Initialize(true);
```

**Here is the error:**

```
Model compatibility cannot be checked because the database does not contain model metadata. Model compatibility can only be checked for databases created using Code First or Code First Migrations.
```

I read that adding

```
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<IncludeMetadataConvention>();
```

to the context class might fix it but it did not in my case. I am not sure where to go next as far as troubleshooting this.

**Questions**

Should I not of created the database ahead of time?
Any ideas would be thoroughly appreciated!

**Here is the code in Global.asax**

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {

        Database.SetInitializer(new ClubLocatorInitializer());
        LocatorContext c = new LocatorContext(); 
        c.Database.Initialize(true);


        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);


    }
```

**Here is the code in my context class**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using ClubLocator.Models;
using ClubLocator.Models.ViewModels;

namespace ClubLocator.DAL
{
    public class LocatorContext : DbContext
    {


      public DbSet<Prospect> Prospects { get; set; }

      protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
      {
          modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<IncludeMetadataConvention>();
          modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
      }





    }
}
```

**Here is my initializer**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Validation;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using ClubLocator.Models;

namespace ClubLocator.DAL
{
    public class ClubLocatorInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<LocatorContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(LocatorContext context)
        {

            var prospect = new List<Prospect>
                              {
                                  new Prospect{


                                          FirstName = "John",
                                          LastName = "Smith",
                                          Email = "jsmith@example.com"
                                  }


                              };
           prospect.ForEach(r => context.Prospects.Add(r));
            context.SaveChanges();


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Arthur Vickers made a great post about the caveats of the "code-first to existing database" approach: http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2012/02/26/dont-use-code-first-by-mistake/

Comment: You can also reverse-engineer a code-first model from an existing database using the EF power tools:
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d